# Getting "select" box to load dynamically in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have a Group object and a Kid object, as well as a Log object. Group hasmany kids, kid belongsto group, and group hasmany logs and kid hasmany logs. To add a log, the user will select a group as well as any number of kids for that log.  The idea is that after selecting a group from this dropdown, the `$this->Form->input('kid_id',array('multiple'=>'true'))` will dynamically populate with any kids that have that associated group_id.  I was thinking I could use $this->redirect() to reload the page, but how can I get it to save the group_id value when it reloads this second input?

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('group_id', array('empty'=>'Select Group'));
    echo $this->Form->input('kid_id',array('multiple'=>'true'));
    echo $this->Form->input('date');
    echo $this->Form->input('volunteers');
?>
```

Comment: You could use Ajax to do it, or save a session variable containing your selection. In this case, Ajax is probably a better solution as you won't have to reload the page.

Comment: Yep, definitely use ajax.